# Modify .bashrc and .Xdefaults

Tags: unix, xterm, bash

I know there mush be a million answers to this question but since all the answers I get are much in depth then I address this simple questions: I would like to modify my .bashrc and .Xdefaults such that instead of gray background and black font to have black background and green font and some different color scheme for symbolic links etc. and the changes to stick once I log out and log in again.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

See [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/) and have this [ANSI escape code sequence reference from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) as reference.

Basically you'd find the part in your RC files where PS1 is set-up. It depends on the distro.

See [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

Of course sometimes you don't have to modify the global files e.g. `/etc/profile*`. You can just add your settings in some local rc file like `.bash_profile`.